# Separation of variables for nonhomogeneous equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, wave-equation

I’m trying to learn PDE from 
**An introduction to partial differential equations, Pinchover and Rubinstein.**
On *page 114* *section 5.4* it explains the use of separation of variables for nonhomogeneous equations.
For example, consider the problem$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\cos(2\pi x)\cos(2\pi t), x>0, x<1 ,t>0$$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0, t\geqslant 0$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)= \cos^2(\pi x), x\geqslant 0, x\leq 1$$
$$u_t(x,0)=g(x)=2\cos(2\pi x), x\geqslant 0, x\leq 1.$$
The system of all eigenfunctions and the corresponding eigenvalues of the homogeneous problem are:
$$X_n(x)=\cos(n\pi x), \lambda_n=(n\pi)^2, n=0,1,2,...$$
For a fixed $t$ the solution $u$ can be represented as 
$$u(x,t)=(\frac{1}{2}) T_0(t) + \sum_{n=1} ^ {\infty} T_n(t)\cos(n\pi x)$$ where $T_n(t)$ are the (time dependent) Fourier coefficients of the function $u(.,t)$!!!

Can anyone please explain what is going on? How one can solve a nonhomogeneous wave equation using separation of variables method and the idea behind it ?
Thanks.

Comment: [See here.](http://www.math.psu.edu/wysocki/M412/Notes412_10.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the initial boundary problem
 $$
 \left\{ 
\begin{array}{lll}
&u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=F(x,t),\; a<x<b,\; t>0,\\
&\text{homogeneous boundary conditions on } (a,b),\\
&u(x,0)=f(x),\; a<x<b,\\
&u_t(x,0)=g(x),\; a<x<b.
\end{array}
\right.
\qquad(1)
$$
Solving steps:

- Solve eigenvalue problem
  $$-X_k''=\lambda_k X_k,$$
  with homogeneous boundary conditions on $(a,b)$.
- Find  Fourier series expansions
  $$F=\sum F_kX_k,$$
  $$f=\sum f_kX_k,$$
  $$g=\sum g_kX_k.$$
- Solve ODE problems
  $$T''_k(t)+c^2\lambda_kT_k(t)=F_k,\; T_k(0)=f_k,\;T'_k(0)=g_k.$$
- Then solution of $(1)$ is
  $$u=\sum T_k(t)X_k$$

For example, consider the problem(Pinchover and Rubinstein, An introduction to partial differential equations, p. 114, section 5.4)
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&u_{tt}-u_{xx}=\cos2\pi x\cos2\pi t,\; 0<x<1,\; t>0,\\
&u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0,\;t\ge0,\\
&u(x,0)=\cos^2\pi x,\; 0\le x\le 1,\\
&u_t(x,0)=2\cos2\pi x,\; 0\le x\le 1.\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

- Solutions of eigenvalue problem 
  $$-X_k''=\lambda_k X_k,\;X'_k(0)=X'_k(1)=0$$
  is 
  $$X_k(x)=\cos(k\pi x),\quad \lambda_k=(k\pi)^2,\quad k=0,1,2,\dots$$
- $F=\cos2\pi x\cos2\pi t$.  Then
  $$F_k=\begin{cases} \cos2\pi t \text{ if } k=2, & \\ 0 \text{ if } k\neq2. \end{cases}$$
  $f=\cos^2\pi x=\frac12+\frac{\cos2\pi x}{2}$. Then
  $$f_k=\begin{cases} \frac12 \text{ if } k=0\quad \text{or} \quad k=2, & \\ 0 \text{ in other cases} \end{cases}$$
  $g=2\cos2\pi x$. Then 
  $$g_k=\begin{cases} 2\text{ if } k=2, & \\ 0 \text{ if } k\neq2. \end{cases}$$
- If $k=0$ then $X_0=1$, $\lambda_0=0$, ODE problem is 
  $$T''_0(t)=0,\; T_k(0)=\frac12,\;T'_k(0)=0.$$

If $k=2$ then  $\lambda_2=4\pi^2$, ODE problem is 
$$T''_2(t)+4\pi^2T_2(t)=\cos2\pi t,\; T_2(0)=\frac12,\;T'_2(0)=2.$$
We obtain $$T_0(t)=\frac12,$$
$$T_2(t)=\frac{\left( t+4\right)  \sin{ 2\pi  t }}{4\pi }+\frac{\cos{ 2\pi  t }}{2},$$
$$T_k(t)=0 \text{ if } k\neq0,\;2.$$

- Final solution is
  $$u=T_0(t)X_0+T_2(t)X_2=
  \frac12+\left(\frac{\left( t+4\right)  \sin{ 2\pi  t }}{4\pi }+\frac{\cos{ 2\pi  t }}{2}\right)\cos 2\pi x$$